# VLOOKUP returning ELSE values for exact matches?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm new to VBA and I can't seem to figure out why my code is not working.

I'm trying to `VLOOKUP` values in the `Z` column to see if there are any "NO" or "NOT SURE" values and return a value such as "N" in the `BB` column if there's a match.

```
Sub comp()
Dim sRange As String
Dim result As String
sRange = "z:z"

If sRange = "NO" Or sRange = "NOT SURE" Then
   result = "N"
Else
   result = "Y"
End If
Range("bb2").Value = result
End Sub
```

I have no clue why it's not returning "N" for the "NO" and "NOT SURE" entries. All the values are returned as "Y".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could add or amend a line so that it shows you the value of sRange.. I dont know much excel vba but maybe like `result = "Y"+sRange`     or `Range("....").Value=sRange`

Comment: also (i'm totally guessing) but maybe this line `sRange = "z:z"` might be wrong.. maybe you're assigning it a literal string.. and then perhaps you are mistakenly testing a range for a literal string.  your issue is probably related to those kind of things

Comment: @barlop is absolutely correct.  And you are even declaring sRange as a string.

Answer (score 0):

*Your code is returning Y in place of N, because for the `sRange` variable you have assigned entire Z column, in this case you need to fill entire Z column with either NO or NOT SURE.* And I'm sure you have not did this.

I'm suggesting you the modified version which comprises only few rows in the Z column and in this case the VB codes returns N.

```
Sub comp()

Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("Z1:Z10")

        If (c.Value = "NO") Or (c.Value = "NOT SURE") Then

            Range("b2").Value = "N"
            Else
            Range("b2").Value = "Y"

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Check the Screen Shot below:

[image]

**Note,** adjust the data range as you need.